# How can I repalce values only if conditioin is True?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe such as:

```
df = pd.read_excel(io = "☆ TOTAL_1320 - mydata.xlsx", sheet_name = 'Sheet1', index_col = 0)
df2 = df

    EXCLUDE PERSONCONCERNED PC_DK   PC_SPOUSE   PC_PARENT   PC_GRANDPARENT  PC_CHILD    PC_SIBSHIP  PC_RELATIVE PC_LOVER    ... WARNEMOTION2    TIME10  WARNEMOTION3    TIME11  WARNEMOTION4    WARNEMOTION4DTL TIME12  WARNSIGN_DTL    EVENT_DTL   EVENT_DTL_2
14  NaN 1   NaN 1.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 ... 2.0 NaN 1.0 88.0    2.0 NaN NaN NaN *** *** ** **/_x000D_\n*** ****** ** ***** ...  NaN
68  NaN 1   NaN 1.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0
```

and I made a condition like this:

```
condition = (df2.PERSONCONCERNED==1) & ((df2.PC_SPOUSE.isnull()==True)
                                    & (df2.PC_PARENT.isnull()==True) & (df2.PC_GRANDPARENT.isnull()==True) 
                                    & (df2.PC_CHILD.isnull()==True) & (df2.PC_SIBSHIP.isnull()==True) 
                                    & (df2.PC_RELATIVE.isnull()==True) & (df2.PC_LOVER.isnull()==True) 
                                    & (df2.PC_FRIEND.isnull()==True) & (df2.PC_STRANGER.isnull()==True) 
                                    & (df2.PC_ETC.isnull()==True))
```

when I do `df2[condition]['PC_DK']` I get this:

```
9089       1.0
20082      NaN
20087      NaN
20090      NaN
20096      NaN
30957      NaN
34196      NaN
81293      NaN
104381    88.0
Name: PC_DK, dtype: float64
```

I want to replace `NaN` values and `1` value to `88` in `df2`(which is the original dataframe)

I could replace them in new dataframe by doing

```
df_condition = df2[condition]['PC_DK']

df_condition = df_condition.replace(np.nan, 88)
df_condition = df_condition.replace(1,88)
```

but I really don't know how to do it with original dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before getting started, first thing is `isnull()` itself returns Boolean value so no need to compare it against `True` , second thing is as you want to check for `null` in multiple columns combined by `&` , you can consolidate these in to `isnull()` and `all()` passing axis parameter. So, the reduced code will look something like this:

```py
# cols is list of columns i.e. cols = ['PC_SPOUSE', 'PC_PARENT', ..., etc.]

condition = df2.PERSONCONCERNED==1 & df2[cols].isnull().all(axis=1)
```

Now to replace, you can directly use the mask created above, then replace the values using `loc`, and as you want to add more condition to replace the values, you can create the extra mask and again combine with `&`:

```py
extra_mask = df2['PC_DK'].isna() | df2['PC_DK'].eq(1)
df2[condition & extra_mask, 'PC_DK'] = 88
```